# puppeteer-cluster@0.20.0 requires a peer of puppeteer@^1.5.0 || ^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: puppeteer

`package.json`:

```json
{
"dependencies": {
    "@flood/element": "^1.2.3",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "ask-sdk": "^2.11.0",
    "ask-sdk-express-adapter": "^2.11.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1048.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "btoa-atob": "^0.1.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.12.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mssql": "^5.1.5",
    "node-html-to-image": "^3.2.0",
    "node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "puppeteer-cluster": "0.20.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.2",
    "tunnel": "0.0.6",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "puppeteer": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/dialogflow": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.39",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^5.4.4",
    "@types/puppeteer-core": "^5.4.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.10.0",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  }
}
```

also, installed puppeteer@5.5 but still facing error as:

> puppeteer-cluster@0.20.0 requires a peer of puppeteer@^1.5.0 || ^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

searched for peer of puppeteer, but not getting any link to install peer dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peer error is coming from [`puppeteer-cluster`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster). It seems that the `puppeteer-cluster` `puppeteer` version is outdated compared to the `puppeteer` version you're running at the root of the project (mismatch between `13.0.1` and `13.0.0`).

`puppeteer-cluster` has its own `puppeteer` version. You don't need to install both packages (even tho it says so in the documentation).

1. `npm uninstall puppeteer`
2. `npm uninstall puppeteer-cluster`
3. `npm i puppeteer-cluster`

If that doesn't fix it you could always force `puppeteer-cluster` install through `npm i puppeteer-cluster --force`.